Psexec cannot access windows 11 24h2
I am used to using PSEXEC on windows 10 and windows 11 23h2. But it isn't working on WINDOWS 11 24H2. The output error is:
Couldn't access COMPUTER-NAME:
The network path was not found.
Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on COMPUTER-NAME

I tried some tips to enable default share, but it still doesn't work.
